# Is there a way to preserve order while round-trip dumping YAML in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to load some data from a YAML-file and put it back:

```
services:
  dc01:
    sw-06-50001:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
    sw-09-50002:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50002, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50002, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50002}
    sw-06-50003:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50003, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50003, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50003}
    sw-09-50004:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50004, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50004, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50004}
```

with this:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
with open('filename.yml', 'r') as stream:
    outdata = yaml.load(stream,Loader=yaml.Loader)

yaml.dump(outdata,'filename_out.yml')
```

I need to preserve all the formatting and data order in the list, but the output dump results in a sorting in alphabetical order by the sw-xx.. key:

```
services:
  dc01:
    sw-06-50001:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}

    sw-06-50003:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50003, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50003, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50003}
    sw-09-50002:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50002, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50002, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50002}
    sw-09-50004:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50004, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50004, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50004}
```

How could I keep an original order of the entries while dumping?

Comment: You can't because that's not a list.

Comment: in module ruamel.yaml there is custom ordereddict() used, instead of dict(), so usage of dictionary is not an issue here. As @Anthon said, the issue was in using of outdated library compatibility instead of normal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a round-trip, but you are not using ruamel.yaml's round-trip feature. Instead you are
using the outdated PyYAML compatibility `load` and `dump` functions.

Instead you should instantiate a `ruamel.yaml.YAML()` instance and use that instance's `load` and `dump` methods,
they default to round-trip with preservation of order (and comments, tag names, etc.)

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
services:
  dc01:
    sw-06-50001:  # first
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
    sw-09-50002:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50002, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50002, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50002}
    sw-06-50003:  # third
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50003, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50003, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50003}
    sw-09-50004:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50004, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50004, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50004}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
services:
  dc01:
    sw-06-50001:  # first
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
    sw-09-50002:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50002, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50002, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50002}
    sw-06-50003:  # third
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50003, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50003, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50003}
    sw-09-50004:
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.18, port: 50004, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.19, port: 50004, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50004}
```

Or in case you have your YAML in a file:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

# the recommended extension for YAML files has been .yaml since 2006.
file_name = Path('filename.yaml')  
file_out = Path('filename_out.yaml')

yaml = YAML()
outdata = yaml.load(file_name)
yaml.dump(outdata, file_out)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! When i started to investigate that behavior i'd noticed it was usind the dict() instead of ordereddict() as it should, according to your module documentation, but didn't know about that compatibility stuff. BTW, in this case, can I put some keys in this ordered dict on a certain position (let's say,  add another  "sw-XX-" in the middle of an ordereddict() to keep custom sorting in place?

Comment: The `outdata['services']['dc01']` is an instance of a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` and that class has a `insert(self, pos, key, value, comment=None)` method.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for help!