# How to define a style of new dictionary in ruamel yaml?

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

As the question [Is there a way to preserve order while round-trip dumping YAML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61989767/) got solved, data structures are correctly imported, with  style attributes set properly, etc. 
I've wrote some code to insert a nested CommentedMap() dictionary (sw-99-54321), which contains  some dictionaries and lists, like:

```
  dc01:
    sw-06-50001:  # existing entry
      servers:
      - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
      - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
      virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}

    sw-99-54321:  # the entry I am trying to add   
      servers:
      - ip: 192.168.1.1
        port: '65535'
        weight: 100
      - ip: 192.168.1.2
        port: '65534'
        weight: 90
      virtual:
        ip: 192.168.1.1
        port: 65532
```

I want to format "sw-99-54321" in the same manner as existed "sw-06-50001.

I know the style is bound to `<var>.fa.__flow_style` attribute, but I can't change it directly:

```
data['services']['dc01']['sw-99-54321']['servers'].fa.set_flow_style='True'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Format' object attribute 'set_flow_style' is read-only
```

Is there a way to set it, or to define block style for some elements in other way?

Comment: Please note that it is "I'm" or "I am" but never "I'am"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your example has flow style you can do two things

1) Set flow style explicitly:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
dc01:
  sw-06-50001:  #existed entry
    servers:
    - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
    - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['dc01']['sw-99-54321'] = n = {}
n['servers'] = l = []
l.append(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('ip', '192.168.1.1'), ('port', '65535'), ('weight', 100)]))
l[-1].fa.set_flow_style()
l.append(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('ip', '192.168.1.2'), ('port', '65534'), ('weight', 90)]))
l[-1].fa.set_flow_style()
n['virtual'] = x = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('ip', '192.168.1.1'), ('port', '65532')])
x.fa.set_flow_style()

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
dc01:
  sw-06-50001:  #existed entry
    servers:
    - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
    - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
  sw-99-54321:
    servers:
    - {ip: 192.168.1.1, port: '65535', weight: 100}
    - {ip: 192.168.1.2, port: '65534', weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.1, port: '65532'}
```

2) Set all leaf nodes to flow style globally:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
dc01:
  sw-06-50001:  #existed entry
    servers:
    - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
    - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = None

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['dc01']['sw-99-54321'] = n = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
n['servers'] = l = []
l.append(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('ip', '192.168.1.1'), ('port', '65535'), ('weight', 100)]))
l.append(dict(ip='192.168.1.2', port='65534', weight=90))
n['virtual'] = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('ip', '192.168.1.1'), ('port', '65532')])

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
dc01:
  sw-06-50001:  #existed entry
    servers:
    - {ip: 10.255.206.12, port: 50001, weight: 100}
    - {ip: 10.255.206.13, port: 50001, weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.4, port: 50001}
  sw-99-54321:
    servers:
    - {ip: 192.168.1.1, port: '65535', weight: 100}
    - {ip: 192.168.1.2, port: '65534', weight: 90}
    virtual: {ip: 192.168.1.1, port: '65532'}
```

with this method it is not necessary to create `CommentedMap()` instances, you can use normal dicts

Answer (score 1):

Finally, 
`data['services']['dc01']['sw-99-54321']['servers'].fa.set_block_style()` 
did the formatting I wanted. While 
`data['services']['dc01']['sw-99-54321']['servers'].fa.set_flow_style()` 
makes the opposite.

Comment: In your example the sequence that is the value for the key `'servers'` is already block style, so that was not what did make the necessary change.

Comment: It was just an example of what happened when I was trying to modify the style. Sorry for disambiguity.